# Getting CAPTCHA to work with Freeform

Tags: solspace-freeform, captcha

I'm trying to add a CAPTCHA to a Freeform (free version) form.

The form is a callback request form that features in the header of the site, so is visible on every page and is not linked to a specific channel.

I've got the CAPTCHA to show up but the form can be submitted with the CAPTCHA text field left blank.

Anyone know a good way of using a CAPTCHA with Solspace's Freeform in this way?

Answer (score 2):

After hours of digging (never worked with ExpressionEngine before) I found out why it was not working in our setup (EE v2.8.1, Freeform Pro 4.1.7). Leaving this here for anybody else looking for the answer:

Go to **CP > Admin > Security and Privacy > CAPTCHA Preferences**. There you will find two input fields that were empty in the site I was working on: "**Server Path to CAPTCHA Folder**" and "**Full URL to CAPTCHA Folder**". Fill these out.

The last one should probably be "/images/captchas" and the first depends on your server. You can find the correct path using PHP's getcwd. It should look something like "/var/www/vhosts/[...]/public_html/images/captchas". This folder should be writable.

After that the Captcha finally showed up.

A few dead ends, to help redirect misguided searches:

- The "{captcha}" or "{freeform:captcha}" EE template code was not the issue
- CAPTCHA being disabled for logged in members was not the issue
- "Enable Membership CAPTCHA" was not the issue (I think this related to registering, which we don't use)

Comment: Helped me. Thanks

Comment: This link was also useful to get Captchas working - https://web.archive.org/web/20140701081945/http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation there is a parameter to make sure the [captcha is required](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#require_captcha)

This assumes you are using the [freeform captcha](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#freeform_captcha) not the default ExpressionEngine one.

If you have done these things already, please edit your question to include your code.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, I'm actually using the free version of Freeform and it appears these features are limited to the paid version?

Comment: That's not correct, you can get the captcha to work with the free version too :) Be default captchas are disabled for logged in members. Go to Admin > Security and Privacy > CAPTCHA Preferences and check the "Require CAPTCHA with logged-in members?". i typically test in Google Incognito mode too then you can see if that's your issue too.